# Variadic template for compile-time type selection based on condition

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, type-traits

In trying to better understand variadic templates, I set myself the task of writing a compile-time type selector based on a given condition (chosen among the ones defined in `<type_traits>`, e.g. `std::is_signed`, `std::is_floating_point` etc.). The selector should pick the first type that meets the condition among those specified as template arguments.

To give you an example:

```
template<template<typename> class Cond, typename... T> 
struct first_if_any {
    // some code here
};

first_if_any<std::is_signed, unsigned, long, int>::type a; // long
first_if_any<std::is_unsigned, short, unsigned long, unsigned>::type b; // unsigned long
first_if_any<std::is_floating_point, int, float, double>::type c; // float
```

These are the features I'd like my selector to have:

1. choose the first type if no type meets the condition
2. print a user-friendly compilation error if no types are specified

Thus:

```
first_if_any<std::is_unsigned, long, int>::type a; // long
first_if_any<std::is_arithmetic>::type b; // ERROR
```

Here's what I came up with (see working example [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8d06d01991955237)):

```
template<template<typename> class Cond, typename... T> 
struct first_if_any {
    using type = void;
    static constexpr bool found = false;
};

template<template<typename> class Cond, typename First, typename... T> 
struct first_if_any<Cond, First, T...> {
    using type = typename std::conditional<Cond<First>::value || !first_if_any<Cond, T...>::found, First, typename first_if_any<Cond, T...>::type>::type;
    static constexpr bool found = Cond<First>::value || first_if_any<Cond, T...>::found;
};
```

This selects types as expected, and meets requirement 1. Now for my questions:

- **How can I meet requirement 2**, i.e. generate a user-friendly compile error if someone tries to use the selector without passing types to it?
- **Is there a better way to do this** (using only standard library features)?

Bonus question, if anyone cares to elaborate:

- Does this qualify as template metaprogramming?

Comment: With `template<template<typename> class Cond, typename T, typename... Ts> struct first_if_any;`, compiler would produce error at usage point for missing template parameter, as you require at least one, so replace your base class by your specialization.

Comment: @Jarod42: is [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8b7289da1e271521) what you mean? Compiler complains: "class template partial specialization does not specialize any template argument".

Comment: Not exactly, like [that](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9afc91cc46d50934). I also have to change the definition BTW (And [with error message](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/47a9781222468d37))

Comment: Problem with your current implementation is that you want to forbid `first_if_any<Cond>`, but you use it (`first_if_any<Cond, T...>` when `T...` is ... empty).

Comment: @Jarod42: got it. Thanks, this is great stuff. It more than qualifies as an answer to both my questions, post one if you will.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To have nice error message, you have to change your declaration to

```
template<template<typename> class Cond, typename T, typename... Ts>
struct first_if_any;
```

so `first_if_any<Cond>` would produce message similar to:

> error: too few template arguments for class template 'first_if_any'

Then, problem with your current implementation is that you use what you want to forbid, I mean `first_if_any<Cond>` (with the various `first_if_any<Cond, T...>` where `T...` can be empty).

You can use intermediate class which handle default type easier with:

```
template<template<typename> class Cond, typename Default, typename... Ts>
struct first_if_any_or_default;

template<template<typename> class Cond, typename Default>
struct first_if_any_or_default<Cond, Default>
{
    using type = Default;
    static constexpr bool found = false;
};

template<template<typename> class Cond, typename Default, typename T, typename... Ts>
struct first_if_any_or_default<Cond, Default, T, Ts...>
{
private:
    using next = first_if_any_or_default<Cond, Default, Ts...>;
public:
    using type = typename std::conditional<Cond<T>::value,
                                           T,
                                           typename next::type>::type;
    static constexpr bool found = Cond<T>::value || next::found;
};

template<template<typename> class Cond, typename First, typename... Ts> 
struct first_if_any {
private:
    using helper = first_if_any_or_default<Cond, First, First, Ts...>;
public:
    using type = typename helper::type;
    static constexpr bool found = helper::found;
};
```